# Get longest distance from series containing comma-separated strings with multiple distance/direction pairs

Tags: python, pandas

I'll preface by saying I have a solution, but it feels overly complicated and inefficient and I'm looking to improve on it.

I have a series inside a dataframe that looks like:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Distance':[None,None,'13',None,'38.12','5NW','1N,3SW,8.3E',None,'2,7']})
>>> df

      Distance
0         None
1         None
2           13
3         None
4        38.12
5          5NW
6    1N,3,8.3E
7         None
8          2,7
```

The non-None values are always strings, and each string is a comma-separated list of distances, each of which might have a fractional part and might not be followed by a cardinal direction. Cardinal directions are always represented as one of the following:

```
N
E
S
W
NE
NW
SE
SW
```

My current goal is to split this column into three:

- A column for the greatest distance, represented as a float (I want to do math on it later)
- A column for the cardinal direction associated with the greatest value, if present
- A column for any remaining distances/directions, represented as a list of strings

So, for the input above, the desired output would be something like:

```
   Distance Direction Additional_Values
0       NaN      None              None
1       NaN      None              None
2     13.00      None              None
3       NaN      None              None
4     38.12      None              None
5      5.00        NW              None
6      8.30         E         [1N, 3SW]
7       NaN      None              None
8      7.00      None               [2]
```

So far I'm doing it like this:

```
>>> helper = df['Distance'].str.extractall(r'(?P<distance>[\d\.]+)(?P<direction>[NESW]*)') #Get each distance + possible direction and explode to one row per value / value pair
>>> helper['distance'] = helper['distance'].astype(float) #Convert distances to float
>>> helper.index.set_names('orig_id',level=0,inplace=True) #Give the level 0 index a name for convenience
>>> helper

               distance direction
orig_id match                    
2       0         13.00       NaN
4       0         38.12       NaN
5       0          5.00        NW
6       0          1.00         N
        1          8.30         E
        2          3.00        SW
8       0          2.00       NaN
        1          7.00       NaN

>>> helperMax = helper.sort_values('distance').reset_index().drop_duplicates('orig_id',keep='last') #Get maximum distance for each index from the original df
>>> helperMax = helperMax.sort_values('orig_id').set_index(['orig_id','match']) #Convert columns back to MultiIndex
>>> helperMax

               distance direction
orig_id match                    
2       0         13.00       NaN
4       0         38.12       NaN
5       0          5.00        NW
6       1          8.30         E
8       1          7.00       NaN

>>> helperRemaining = helper.drop(index=helperMax.index) #Get remaining value pairs by dropping indices of max values
>>> helperRemaining['concat'] = helperRemaining['distance'].astype(str) + helperRemaining['direction'].fillna('') #Concat value pairs back into strings
>>> helperRemaining = helperRemaining.groupby('orig_id')['concat'].apply(list) #Group strings into lists
>>> helperRemaining = helperRemaining.reindex(df.index) #Make index match the starting df
>>> helperRemaining

0              NaN
1              NaN
2              NaN
3              NaN
4              NaN
5              NaN
6    [1.0N, 3.0SW]
7              NaN
8            [2.0]

>>> helperMax = helperMax.droplevel('match').reindex(df.index) #Make helperMax index match the starting df
>>> df['Distance'] = helperMax['distance'] #Replace original df column with max values

>>> # Insert Direction column (df actually has many columns and order matters)
>>> df.insert(
>>>     df.columns.get_loc('Distance') + 1,
>>>     'Direction',
>>>     helperMax['direction']
>>> )

>>> # Insert Additional_Values column
>>> df.insert(
>>>     df.columns.get_loc('Direction') + 1,
>>>     'Additional_Values',
>>>     helperRemaining
>>> )

>>> df

   Distance Direction Additional_Values
0       NaN       NaN               NaN
1       NaN       NaN               NaN
2     13.00       NaN               NaN
3       NaN       NaN               NaN
4     38.12       NaN               NaN
5      5.00        NW               NaN
6      8.30         E     [1.0N, 3.0SW]
7       NaN       NaN               NaN
8      7.00       NaN             [2.0]
```

This gets an acceptable result, but it's a lot of steps to get there. What can I do to condense this into something less complicated, and hopefully speed it up along the way?

Sidenote: I know the first three lines of my process immediately produce output in First Normal Form, and thus they'd better fit with data management best practices. Unfortunately, for compatibility reasons I can only have one table. Additionally: A column must be a single data type, and can contain lists of varying length as long as all elements across all lists are of the same data type. If there's a better way to format my table that fits those constraints and allows me to do math on the max distance, I'm all ears.

**Edit to clarify:** When the max value occurs more than once, I want to get exactly one of them and send the rest to Additional_Values. Direction doesn't matter for this selection (aside from keeping any directions paired with their associated distances); I'm okay with e.g. sorting purely by distance and getting whichever one happens to be last.

Comment: You mention that you’re concerned about performance, but don’t mention where the bottleneck is. If you want to improve performance, find the bottleneck and ask specific questions about that

Comment: Apologies, I haven't investigated for an actual bottleneck; I'm primarily concerned with simplifying the code for readability, and am worried about performance almost as an afterthought. My intuition is that the number of transformations I'm doing could slow things down and the three new dataframes could potentially overtax memory, but in my case I'm operating on a small enough dataset that I don't expect to notice it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Distance": [None, None, "13", None, "38.12", "5NW", "1N,3SW,8.3E", None, "2,7"]}
)

pat = re.compile(r"^\d+\.?\d*")
mask = df["Distance"].isna()

x = (
    df.loc[~mask, "Distance"]
    .apply(
        lambda x: sorted(
            x.split(","),
            key=lambda k: float(pat.search(k).group(0)),
            reverse=True,
        ),
    )
    .to_frame()
)

x["Distance2"] = x["Distance"].str[0].str.extract(r"^(\d+\.?\d*)")
x["Direction"] = x["Distance"].str[0].str.extract(r"([A-Z]*)$").replace("", np.nan)
x["Additional_Values"] = x["Distance"].str[1:].apply(lambda x: x if x else np.nan)

x = x.reindex(df.index)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
          Distance Distance2 Direction Additional_Values
0              NaN       NaN       NaN               NaN
1              NaN       NaN       NaN               NaN
2             [13]        13       NaN               NaN
3              NaN       NaN       NaN               NaN
4          [38.12]     38.12       NaN               NaN
5            [5NW]         5        NW               NaN
6  [8.3E, 3SW, 1N]       8.3         E         [3SW, 1N]
7              NaN       NaN       NaN               NaN
8           [7, 2]         7       NaN               [2]
```

Comment: I wonder why you didn't define `pat` as a group so that you can reuse it as `pat.pattern` when creating `"Distance2"`? Was it intentional or just happened?

Comment: @Vitalizzare Yes, if you define `pat = re.compile(r"^(\d+\.?\d*)")` (notice the capturing group) you can write `x["Distance2"] = x["Distance"].str[0].str.extract(pat)`. I didn't want to use the capturing groups in this compiled pattern so that's why I retyped the regex second time. But, good catch :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possibility as a single pipeline of chained commands.

I don't know if it will be much more efficient than your original logic but it seems organized and easier to read to me.

```
out = (df['Distance']
 # split the values and get a deduplicated index (easier than split+explode)
 .str.extractall(r'(?P<Additional_Values>[^,]+)')
 # split into relevant parts
 .pipe(lambda d: d.join(d['Additional_Values'].str.extract(r'(?P<distance>[\d\.]+)(?P<direction>[NESW]*)')))
 # convert and sort
 .astype({'distance': float}).replace('', float('nan'))
 .sort_values(by='distance')
 # keep only relevant values
 .assign(**{'max': lambda d: d.groupby(level=0)['distance'].transform('max').eq(d['distance']),
            'Additional_Values': lambda d: d['Additional_Values'].mask(d['max']),
           })
 # aggregate
 .groupby(level=0)
 .agg({'distance': 'last',
       'direction': 'last',
       'Additional_Values': lambda x: list(X) if len(X:=x.dropna()) else float('nan')})
 # add missing indiices
 .reindex(df.index)
)
```

Output:

```
   distance direction Additional_Values
0       NaN       NaN               NaN
1       NaN       NaN               NaN
2     13.00      None               NaN
3       NaN       NaN               NaN
4     38.12      None               NaN
5      5.00        NW               NaN
6      8.30         E         [1N, 3SW]
7       NaN       NaN               NaN
8      7.00      None               [2]
```

Comment: Took me a minute to understand why you were doing two separate extracts, but now that I've seen it I like how it avoids splitting+converting the extra values only to undo it later.

Comment: What if one of the records is `'13W,13E'`, for example? Looks like you gonna lose one of the values, no?

Comment: @Vitalizzare this behavior was not defined, if this should happen you can decide to keep both or one with a slight code change

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by _this behavior was not defined_. Here's my point. You are masking **all** the maximum values in `Additional_Values`. Which means that only the last one will remain (due to your `agg` function), and all the others will disappear.

Comment: @Vitalizzare OP didn't define what should happen if there are several max values. Pick one? Which one? All? Keep other? Discard other? There are many ways to handle this and it shouldn't be left to guessing. As direction is not a list, I'm just assuming this does not happen. If it does, this is easy to modify ;)

Comment: @mozway Good point. Added a clarifying note to the end of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option:

```
d = df['Distance'].str.split(',').map(lambda x: sorted(x,key = lambda s: float(re.sub(r'[A-Za-z]','',s))),na_action='ignore').str.join(',')


s = d.str.rsplit(',',n=1)
l = ['N','E','W','NE','NW','SE','SW']

(s.str[-1].str.extract(r'(?P<Distance>[0-9.]+)(?P<Direction>\b{}\b)?'.format('|'.join(l)))
.assign(Additional_Values = s.str[0].where(df['Distance'].str.contains(',')).str.split(','))
.astype({'Distance':'float'}))
```

Output:

```
   Distance Direction Additional_Values
0       NaN       NaN               NaN
1       NaN       NaN               NaN
2     13.00       NaN               NaN
3       NaN       NaN               NaN
4     38.12       NaN               NaN
5      5.00        NW               NaN
6      8.30         E         [1N, 3SW]
7       NaN       NaN               NaN
8      7.00       NaN               [2]
```

Comment: I like the idea, but this is currently assuming the last value in each string is always the maximum, which is not true.  For example, in row 6, this doesn't actually output ```8.30    E    [1N, 3SW]``` as desired, but instead outputs ```3.0    SW    [1N, 8.3E]```.

Comment: I made an edit after rereading the question. Does this fix the issue?

Comment: `map(sorted...` do not work on a non-numerical values as intended. Say, you have a values `"11,1E"`. Which one is bigger with alphanumeric sorting?

Comment: I'm thinking it should work if we use something like ```key=lambda k: float(pat.search(k).group(0))``` from Andrej's answer. Will test when able if nobody beats me to it.

Answer (score 1):

`panas 1.5.1` `python 3.11`

It's a little late to answer, but I like the question. So let's call this *Afterword*.

I believe that once parsed, all directions are better stored as a tuple of tuples rather than a list of strings. Here's my point:

1. Keeping values and directions separated makes life easier in the future.
2. Tuples are immutable thus eliminating the possibility of accidental changes.
3. If you leave the direction value at the first position, then sorting tuples is like sorting distances by value.
4. With a sorted list of tuples, we can easily reach the maximum or minimum direction at index 0 or -1, and the rest by slicing.
5. And I hope it's not that much memory compared to a bunch of unique strings for value-direction pairs (but I haven't delved into that side)

Let's see how it goes:

```
dist_pattern = re.compile(r"^(?P<value>\d+\.?\d*)(?P<direction>(?:N|W|S|E|NW|NE|SW|SE)?)")

distance = (
    df["Distance"]
    .dropna()
    .str.split(',')
    .explode()                        # process each directions separately
    .str.extract(dist_pattern)        # separate value-direction pairs in columns
    .astype({'value': float})
    .sort_values('value')
    .agg(tuple, axis=1)               # combine value-direction pairs
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(tuple)                       # combine sorted distances by index
    .reindex(df.index)
)
```

And I'd leave it at that, i.e. `df['Distance'] = distance`.

We have access to the min and max values with `distance.str[0]` and `distance.str[-1]`. We can calculate statistics for them, like `distance.str[-1].str[0].mean()`. Or, for example, we can sum the values in each direction, like:

```
(
    distance
    .dropna()
    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(*zip(*x)).groupby(level=0).sum())
    .fillna(0)
)
```

What do we do if we have to pass data to others as it's described in the post?

```
helper = (
    distance
    .str[-1]            # extract max direction
    .apply(pd.Series, index=['Distance', 'Direction'])
    .assign(**{         # attach the rest if not empty
        'Additional_Values': (rest:=distance.str[:-1]).where(rest.str.len() > 0)
    })
)

# following the requirement to keep column order
loc_distance = df.columns.get_loc('Distance')
df.insert(loc_distance + 1, 'Direction', np.nan)
df.insert(loc_distance + 2, 'Additional_Values', np.nan)
df[helper.columns] = helper

# if exactly lists of strings required
df['Additional_Values'] = (
    df['Additional_Values']
    .map(lambda x: [''.join(map(str, x)) for x in x], na_action='ignore')
)

# if empty string as a direction isn't appropriate for any reason
df.replace({'Direction':{'': np.nan}}, inplace=True)
```

But I wouldn't do that. IMO this limits the scope for further analysis if needed. And replacing solid data with `nan`, as we did this when removing empty tuples of other distances and replacing empty strings, eventually leads to having to puzzle over what to fill that void with.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case this whole thing lives inside a system that converts the pandas output into its own format, and it does not recognize columns containing tuples of tuples. It can handle one level of nesting, but not two. If it did, this would be my preferred answer. I'm glad you put it here; it'll be of the most value for anyone reading this who doesn't have to deal with my system's limitations.